# Sampling Calculation / multimedia

Tags: sampling, multimedia

I have a serious exam tomorrow and this is one of the sample questions provided. I tried to solve this problem many times but I could never get an accurate answer. There are no information regarding on the calculations in my lecture materials. I googled many things and looked for ways of calculating this in two different books which I have but could not find anything related. I do not know what the exact subject name for these sort of calculations but I think it is multimedia/sampling. I would greatly appreciate any information regarding the problem seriously any briefing would do. I just want to be able to solve it. I have quoted the question below.

"A supermarket must store text, image and video information on 2,000
items. There is text information associated with each item occupying 0.5
Kb. For 200 items, it is also necessary to store an image consisting of 1
million pixels. Each pixel represents one of 255 colours. For 10 items, it is
also necessary to store a 4 second colour video (25 frames per second), to
be viewed on a screen with a resolution of 1000 x 1000 pixels. The total
storage required for the database is:"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about homework, not programming.

Comment: The math is no more difficult than addition and multiplication.  Can you think of nothing?  You've got a serious problem on your hands.

Comment: Why be what way?  This isn't a site to have others do your homework for you.  Stop Googling and start thinking.  1000x1000 pixels = 1 million pixels.  0-255 colors can be represented by 2^8 = 256; 1 byte.  See where this is going?

Comment: Exam, homework - it's all the same.  You didn't pay much attention in class, I suppose.  You'd have better luck if you'd leave off from arguing on SO and start thinking.  You'll fail that exam if you waste all your time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **TOTAL** **=** 2,000 items x 0.5 kilobytes **+**
>   (200 items x (1,000,000 pixels x 1 byte each)) **+**
>   (10 items x (25 frames x 4
>   seconds) x (1,000 pixels x 1,000 pixels x 1 byte each))
>   **=** 1,000,000 + 200,000,000 + 1,000,000,000
>   **=** 1,201,000,000 bytes = 1.201 GB

---

Notes:

Kb could represent either 1000 or 1024, depending on how coherent your syllabus is. I imagine given the choice of the other numbers it is 1,000.

Each of 255 colors can be stored in a single byte TINYINT (as 256 is the TINYINT max).

Comment: Too bad he's off by three orders of magnitude.  It should be 1.201 GB.  Look at the second term - it's 1000 frames of 1 MB each.  That's 1 GB.  I hope you're checking this faulty calculation.

Comment: What's really shameful is being suckered into doing homework assignments by lazy students.  I would have said 1 kB = 1024 bytes.

Comment: The correct answer for 1024 bytes/KB is 1.172 GB.  You realize, of course, that 1024 MB = 1GB.  Good luck on that exam.

Comment: When did I belittle?  I'm instructing both you and the guy who answered your question incorrectly.  I'm telling you how this site is supposed to work.  I'm the ONLY person who gave the correct way to answer this question.  Even the guy who answered your question had to accept instruction.  I tried to persuade you to attempt something and learn for yourself.  You should care more about becoming truly knowledgeable than passing exams.

Comment: Did I miss something in the conversation?

Comment: The OP deleted all his comments out of shame.